# Why is my select element blank when populating State names?

Tags: angular15

```
`import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  OnDestroy,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CourtCity } from '../court-city/court-city';
import { CourtCityService } from '../court-city/court-city.service';
import { CourtState } from '../court-state/court-state';
import { CourtStateService } from '../court-state//court-state.service';
import { Router, Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { of, throwError, interval, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpClientModule,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { SearchPipe } from 'src/app/search.pipe';

declare var window: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-court-city',
  templateUrl: './court-city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./court-city.component.css'],
})
export class CourtCityComponent implements OnInit {
  newcourtCity = {} as CourtCity;
  courtCity = {} as CourtCity;
  courtState = {} as CourtState;
  courtCityId: Number = 0;
  courtStateId: Number = 0;
  displayDialog = true;
  isOpen = false;
  courtCitys: String[] = [];
  courtCityName: String = '';
  courtStateName: String = '';
  id: Number = 0;
  courtCitySubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  courtStateSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  deleteSelected = false;
  editSelected = false;
  addSelected = false;
  dialogcourtCityName: String = '';
  searchText = '';
  state = {} as CourtState;
  searchTextState: String = '';

  formModal: any;

  stringifiedData: any;
  parsedJson: any;

  stringifiedDataCity: any;
  parsedJsonCity: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private courtCityService: CourtCityService,
    private courtStateService: CourtStateService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formModal = new window.bootstrap.Modal(
      document.getElementById('myModal')
    );
    this.createDelayUsingTimer(1000, 3000);
    this.courtStateSubscription = this.courtStateService
      .getCourtStates()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log('Stringfied Data :' + this.stringifiedData);
          this.parsedJson = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedData);
          console.log('Parsed Json Message :' + this.parsedJson.message);
        },

        (err): void => {
          alert('Parsed JSON : ' + this.parsedJson.data);
          console.log(err.error.message);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('Completed!!!!');
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.courtCitySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.courtStateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onAddClicked() {
    this.addSelected = true;
    this.editSelected = false;
    this.deleteSelected = false;
    this.courtCityId = 0;
    this.courtCityName = '';
    this.formModal.show();
  }

  onEditClicked(id: Number, type: String) {
    this.editSelected = true;
    this.addSelected = false;
    this.deleteSelected = false;
    this.courtCityId = id;
    this.courtCityName = type;
    this.formModal.show();
  }

  onDeleteClicked(id: Number, type: String) {
    this.deleteSelected = true;
    this.addSelected = false;
    this.editSelected = false;
    this.courtCityId = id;
    this.courtCityName = type;
    this.formModal.show();
  }

  // onSubmit() {
  //   alert('searchText: ' + this.searchText);
  //   document.getElementById('myForm');
  // }

  onAdd() {
    // this.courtCity.courtCityId = 0;
    alert('Add : ' + this.courtStateId);
    this.courtCity.courtStateId = this.courtStateId;
    this.courtCity.courtCityName = this.courtCityName;
    this.createDelayUsingTimer(1000, 5000);
    this.courtCitySubscription = this.courtCityService
      .addCourtCity(this.courtCity)
      .subscribe(
        (data): void => {
          this.stringifiedDataCity = JSON.stringify(data);
          this.parsedJsonCity = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedDataCity);
          // alert(this.parsedJsonCity.message);
          location.reload();
        },
        (err: any): void => {
          alert('Inside error');
          alert('Add Error: ' + err.error.message);
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
        },
        (): void => {
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
          console.log('Insert Completed!!!!');
        }
      );
    this.courtCityId = 0;
    this.courtCityName = '';
    this.formModal.hide();
  }

  onUpdate(): void {
    this.courtCity.courtCityId = this.courtCityId;
    this.courtCity.courtCityName = this.courtCityName;
    this.createDelayUsingTimer(1000, 5000);
    this.courtCitySubscription = this.courtCityService
      .updateCourtCity(this.courtCity)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.stringifiedDataCity = JSON.stringify(data);
          this.parsedJsonCity = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedDataCity);
          alert(this.parsedJsonCity.message);
          location.reload();
        },
        (err) => {
          alert('Inside Update Error');
          alert('Update error: ' + err.error.message);
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
        },
        () => {
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
          console.log('Update Completed!!!!');
        }
      );
    this.courtCityId = 0;
    this.courtCityName = '';
    this.formModal.hide();
  }

  onDelete() {
    this.courtCity.courtCityId = this.courtCityId;
    this.courtCity.courtCityName = this.courtCityName;
    this.createDelayUsingTimer(1000, 3000);
    this.courtCitySubscription = this.courtCityService
      .deleteCourtCity(this.courtCityId, this.courtCityName)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          // this.stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
          // console.log('Stringfied Data :' + this.stringifiedData);
          // this.parsedJson = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedData);
          // console.log('Parsed Json Message :' + this.parsedJson.message);
          console.log(this.courtCityName + ' Deleted!!!!');
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
          location.reload();
        },
        (error: any) => {
          alert(error.error.message);
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
        },
        () => {
          this.courtCityId = 0;
          this.courtCityName = '';
          console.log('Delete Completed!!!!');
        }
      );
    this.courtCityId = 0;
    this.courtCityName = '';
    this.formModal.hide();
  }

  onClose() {
    this.editSelected = false;
    this.deleteSelected = false;
    this.addSelected = false;
    this.formModal.hide();
  }

  gotocourtCitys() {
    this.router.navigate(['/courtCity']);
  }

  showDialogToAdd() {
    this.newcourtCity = {} as CourtCity;
    this.courtCity = {} as CourtCity;
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }

  onChange(event: any) {
    let strArray: Array<CourtState> = this.parsedJson.data.CourtState;
    for (let len = 0; len < strArray.length; len++) {
      if (strArray[len].courtStateName == event) {
        this.courtStateName = strArray[len].courtStateName;
        this.courtStateId = strArray[len].courtStateId;
      }
    }
    this.createDelayUsingTimer(1000, 3000);
    this.courtCitySubscription = this.courtCityService
      .getCourtCityByStateId(this.courtStateId)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.stringifiedDataCity = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log('Stringfied Data :' + this.stringifiedDataCity);
          this.parsedJsonCity = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedDataCity);
        },
        (err): void => {
          alert(err.error.message);
          console.log(err.error.message);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('Completed!!!!');
        }
      );
  }

  cancel() {
    this.displayDialog = false;
  }

  cleanString(str: string) {
    str = str.replace('"[', '[');
    str = str.replace(']"', ']');
    return str;
  }

  createDelayUsingTimer(delayValue1: number, delayValue2: number) {
    return timer(delayValue1, delayValue2);
  }

  setFocus() {
    var input = document.getElementById('myModal')?.focus();
  }
}
```

This code works like as a component.ts file. Go through the code.It actaully popups modal dialog for CRUD operations. And in the HTML when selecting the CourtState, the select element is populated with the state name available in the database. But it actually retreives the values, but the values are not visible. I can actually scroll thru the list which is blank.Sayy if I have 6 states, then there are 6 options with just blank entries.`

---

```
`
**court-city.component.html
<br />
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-center text-primary">Court City</h4>
  <select
    class="form-control form-select"
    [ngModel]="courtStateName"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
    id="courtStateId"
    name="courtStateName"
    style="margin-right: auto; width: 200px"
  >
    <option selected="selected">Select Court State</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cs of parsedJson.data.CourtState">
      {{ cs.courtStateName }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <button
    style="margin-right: auto; width: 200px"
    class="btn btn-warning mb-3"
    (click)="onAddClicked()"
  >
    Add New Court City
  </button>
  <input
    class="form-control align-right"
    role="search"
    style="width: 350px"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search"
    [(ngModel)]="searchText"
  />

  <div class="fixTableHead">
    <table style="margin-right: auto" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="header bg-info" scope="col">Court City</th>
          <th class="header bg-info text-center" colspan="2" style="width: 7%">
            Action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let courtcity of parsedJsonCity.data.CourtCity">
          <td>{{ courtcity.courtCityName }}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <i
                    class="modal-title text-primary fa fa-solid fa-pencil"
                    id="myModal"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Edit selected Court City"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#myModal"
                    (click)="
                      onEditClicked(
                        courtCity.courtCityId,
                        courtCity.courtCityName
                      )
                    "
                  ></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <i
                    class="text-danger fa fa-solid fa-trash"
                    id="myModal"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Delete selected Court City"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#myModalDelete"
                    (click)="
                      onDeleteClicked(
                        courtCity.courtCityId,
                        courtCity.courtCityName
                      )
                    "
                  >
                  </i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div
    id="myModal"
    class="modal fade"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-hidden="true"
    data-bs-keyboard="false"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            (click)="onClose()"
          >
            &times;
          </button>
          <h5 class="modal-title text-primary">Court City</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <div *ngIf="this.editSelected">
                <label for="courtCity" class="form-label"
                  >Edit Court City</label
                >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="courtCityId"
                  name="courtCityName"
                  [(ngModel)]="courtCityName"
                />
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="this.deleteSelected">
                <label for="courtCity" class="form-label"
                  >Delete Court City</label
                >
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="courtCityId"
                  name="courtCityName"
                  [(ngModel)]="courtCityName"
                  readonly
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <div *ngIf="this.addSelected">
                  <label for="courtCity" class="form-label"
                    >Add New Court City</label
                  >
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="courtCityId"
                    name="courtCityName"
                    [(ngModel)]="courtCityName"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div *ngIf="this.addSelected">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary mt-3"
              (click)="onAdd()"
            >
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="this.editSelected">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning mt-3"
              (click)="onUpdate()"
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="this.deleteSelected">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-danger mt-3"
              (click)="onDelete()"
              value="disabled readonly input"
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning mt-3"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              (click)="onClose()"
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

`The above html file contains the select element which is getting populated wiith court states, but all the entries in the select element is blank. For example, if I have 6 entries all the 6 entries are blank. I can acess each of the blank option. If I comment out the court-city code in HTML file, I can see the entries clearly. Now it is not blank, but populated with states.`